# Asynchronous Data Call & CoreAnimation

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, asynchronous, nsurlconnection

I'm currently doing this:

```
        NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
```

and then I update the UI and run alot of animations to display the data that I just received.

However I am now trying to use an asynchronous request to load the info instead as the above method is locking the main thread.

Any ideas? i've tried setting up an NSOperationQueue and using:

```
                NSData *responseGBP = [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:requestGBP queue:operationQueue completionHandler:nil];
```

However I get this error:  Initializing 'NSData *__strong' with an expression of incompatible type 'void'

Can you geniuses help me?

Comment: sorry I had pasted the wrong code, please check again, its actually a different error message, if you could re-read the question that would be great.

Comment: It's just because that method returns void, as the *NSData* object is passed in the completion handler. So just type *[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:requestGBP queue:operationQueue completionHandler:nil];* and initialize *responseBGP* inside the completion handler.

Comment: oh ok, so how do I set NSData, could you give me the syntax of the call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:* returns void, so you can't initialize the *NSData* object immediately, you need to wait the response, which is asynchronous. So just do something like this:

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:requestGBP queue:operationQueue completionHandler: ^(NSURLResponse* response, NSData* data, NSError* error)
{
    responseBGP= data;
    // Additional code handling the result goes here, not after the call.
}];
// Here responseBGP may be nil as well, you don't know when the concurrent 
// operation will finish.
```

Notice that after you have called this method, isn't said that *responseBGP* will be initialized, because the method is asynchronous, executed on the queue.

Comment: Thanks for the above info! If I have multiple of these requests do I have to nest them or is it ok to perform them serperately one after another?

Comment: With multiple requests things might get complicated, so I recommend to handle them separately. Always remember that if you update the UI, you need to do it on the main thread (*performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:* is your friend).

Comment: yes thanks for all the info! I have it working now... strange alot of times my string I set after the call is null (maybe there is a short timeout on async calls)... another problem I have is that floats I use to keep count of items that I set in the completion block don't seem to stay set, even though I use __block

Comment: Are you logging it after the call? It may be *nil* as well (like every variable written inside the block), see the edited answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help here, i'll ask another question and clarify my current issue... thanks again